# Formula with dynamic reference to a specific cell

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, excel-formula

in the following expression I would like to set B2 dynamic pointing to the right cell where I am inserting the formula:

```
WS1.Cells(4 + j - 1, 3 + ((i - 1) * 9)).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(B2;WS2!B:C;2;FALSE)"
```

How can I achive that?

Comment: If you do not define what `dynamic` means in your context, nobody can help you. Do you want referring the row where the formula is placed? Do you want replacing "B" with a column situated one column before/after the one where the formula is written? That dynamic is now clear only in your head, I'm afraid...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `dynamic` means to reference "B" on the same row with the cell receiving the formula, please try the next way:

```
WS1.Cells(4 + j - 1, 3 + ((i - 1) * 9)).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(B" & 4 + j - 1 & ",WS2!B:C,2,FALSE)"
```

And VBA uses comma as list separator, Independent of localization you should use comma...

**Edited**:
In order to use in formula the cell to the left of the one where the formula is written, plese try the next way:

```
WS1.cells(4 + j - 1, 3 + ((i - 1) * 9)).Formula = _
    "=VLOOKUP(" & WS1.cells(4 + j - 1, 3 + ((i - 1) * 9) - 1).Address(0, 0) & ",WS2!B:C,2,FALSE)"
```

Comment: And what if I would like to parameterize the "B" in the vlookup?
I tried with  "=VLOOKUP(" & W1.Cells(4 + j - 1, 4 + ((i - 1) * 9)) & ",WS2!B:C,2,FALSE)" but it returns blank

Comment: @Gimmy88 The question as you asked does not make too much sense, if you do not explain what "parameterize" should mean... I tried some examples of detaining in my clarification comment. I only tried guessing what you wanted when dared to place an answer...

Comment: I mean that in my first question the (correct) vlookup sentence was "=VLOOKUP(B" & 4 + j - 1 & ",WS2!B:C,2,FALSE)", meaning that the row will always be "B" and the column will change base on the loop counter. Now, what if I want to make also the column change based on the loop counter? I tried "=VLOOKUP(" & W1.Cells(4 + j - 1, 4 + ((i - 1) * 9)) & ",WS2!B:C,2,FALSE)" but it returns blank instead of the row-column name, so how can this be achieved?

Comment: @Gimmy88 I am afraid that what you say is not really correct... The **column is B:B** and the row is changed **according to the one belonging to the cell where the formula to be placed**.  Now, **based on what** to parameterize the column (instead on B)? Then, your previous request required a `Long` number to 'understand' the necessary row. In order to use a column letter, I can show you how to do it, but only if **I will be able to understand what you want**. Only trying something without understanding what it should do, is not a way of learning, I think...

Comment: @Gimmy88 If you tell me what you want in about 5 minutes, I will try helping you. Otherwise, I will leave my office and I will be at home after some hours. Anyhow, if you place a new question asking for what you need, **as our community rules state**, if I will not be available, somebody else may help you. But you must know what you want and how to explain in a way to make us understand your need...

Comment: I don't understand what you don't understand of my request :D I want to put a vlookup function in a cell via vba. In my first question I had the column "B" in the vlookup function always persistent and number dynamic or parameterize or call as you want, meaning that based on the loop count they would be B2, B3, B4 and so. Now, I want that also the row "B" is dynamic based on the loop counter, meaning that it could be B2, C4, E7 and so on. I tried putting " & WS2.Cells(4 + j - 1, 4 + ((i - 1) * 9)) & " instead of  " & 4 + j - 1 & " in the formula, but it returns. Is it clear? :D

Comment: @Gimmy88 I cannot get you, sorry, I am afraid you do not understand a simple issue: Are you able to define **how many columns before of after the one keeping the formula should be the column to be used**? If not, I am afraid I cannot help you. I do not care too much where you use it. In order to help **I need understanding based on what this column can be determined**. It looks that you do  not understand this aspect and I do not know how else to explain what is needed. Another alternative about "not understanding of your request" will be that maybe I am stupid. Now I am closing my laptop.

Comment: Ok clear: the column of the lookup value needs to be the one on the left of cell where the formula reside.

Comment: @Gimmy88 We've started to talk a common language. I will open my laptop in some minutes and edit the answer to make it solving this new request. Even if, the community rule states that a new question was necessary...

Comment: @Gimmy88 Please, test the code after editing and send some feedback.

Comment: It works, the function "address" did the trick, thanks!!